Unstable work of PolynomialMod
I tried to use PolynomialMod for my calculation and i need some help on working with it, because i'll need to use it several hundred times.
I made such a request
In[26]:= PolynomialMod[(v0 + v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5)*(v0^2 + v1^2 + 
 v2^2 + v3^2 + v4^2 + v5^2) - (v0 + v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + 
 v5)^3, {v0 - v1 + v4 + v5, v2 - v5, v3 - v4, v0*v1, v2*v5, v3*v4}]

Out[26]= -4 v1^2 v2 - 4 v1 v2^2 - 4 v1^2 v3 - 40 v1 v2 v3 - 
 2 v2^2 v3 - 4 v1 v3^2 - 2 v2 v3^2

I knew something was wrong, because i knew correct answers. I tried to make some other request and after few attempts i got another result from the same request.
In[33]:= PolynomialMod[(v0 + v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5)*(v0^2 + v1^2 + 
 v2^2 + v3^2 + v4^2 + v5^2) - (v0 + v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + 
 v5)^3, {v0 - v1 + v4 + v5, v2 - v5, v3 - v4, v0*v1, v2*v5, v3*v4}]

Out[33]= -48 v1 v4 v5

Which is great, cause it is correct. I want to understand, how it depends on what is made in kernel or around that calculation. I tried to get first answer but i am not succeeded.
I also tried some request like this
In[72]:= PolynomialMod[(v0 + v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5)*(v0^2 + v1^2 + 
     v2^2 + v3^2 + v4^2 + v5^2) - (v0 + v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + 
     v5)^3, {v0 - v5, v1 - v4, v2 - v3, v0*v5, v1*v4, v2*v3}]

Out[72]= -90 v5^3

Which is obviously wrong, cause i got v0-v5 relation, which gives v0=v5, and v0*v5=v5^2=0.
I am not sure that there is not my fault on some level, cause i don't use Mathematica often and can do some mistakes. Maybe highlighting of text will help understanding that issue:

In your image, v0, v2, v3 are all defined to be something, since they are in black, so I suspect that between In[26] and In[33], you defined those values to be something.  Clear these variables or restart the kernel and try again.  For what it's worth, I get the same thing as you for the first bit of code in your post, but I can't verify whether it's correct or not.

@march When i restart kernel i still got result from In[26] , but the problem is that answer is wrong or better say "raw", for the same reason, as i mentioned in In[72]. Term v2^2 in In[72] must be 0, because v2-v5 is 0, so v5 is v2, and v2v5=v2^2 then. If i add such a induced relations (u can check it by adding v2^2, v4^2, v3^2 - v3v5). I can do it by hands, but as i can see from In[33] there is a way to do it automatically

If you apply PolynomialMod twice you get : -48 v0 v2 v3

@DanielHuber Can u please describe how u get it. I tried to take PolynomialMod with same relations on -4 v1^2 v2 - 4 v1 v2^2 - 4 v1^2 v3 - 40 v1 v2 v3 -   2 v2^2 v3 - 4 v1 v3^2 - 2 v2 v3^2 result i don't get -48 v0 v2 v3. I also tried removing additive or multiplicative relations, but it is not working. I am wondering, if it is working like real relations or there is other principle.

Let's link to this, where Daniel Huber explains a bit more.

I am unable to get to the bottom of the matter, but your problem is related to the fact that modulo an ideal of the ring of polynomials in several variables, there is no unique way to determine a minimal remainder. This in sharp contrast to the case of univariate polynomial rings. This much I know, but the rest of this answer is somewhat speculative, but seems to fit the observations. Here comes.

PolynomialMod seems to subtract a multiple of each and every polynomial in the list. But just once (guessing) – it won't retrace the list the way you seem to want. PolynomialReduce works bit more. Indeed, I got:
In[1]:=PolynomialReduce[(v0 + v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5)*(v0^2 + v1^2 + v2^2 + 
     v3^2 + v4^2 + v5^2) - (v0 + v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5)^3, {v5^2, 
  v4^2, v3 - v4, v2 - v5, v1^2 - v1 v4 - v1 v5, 
  v0 - v1 + v4 + v5}, {v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5}]
Out[1]={{-6 v0 - 14 v1 - 4 v2 - 2 v3 - 2 v4, -6 v0 - 14 v1 - 10 v2 - 4 v3 + 
   6 v5, -2 v0^2 - 6 v0 v1 - 2 v1^2 - 6 v0 v2 - 6 v1 v2 - 2 v2^2 - 
   2 v0 v3 - 2 v1 v3 - 2 v2 v3 - 8 v0 v4 - 8 v1 v4 - 8 v2 v4 - 
   2 v3 v4 - 6 v0 v5 - 6 v1 v5 - 6 v2 v5 - 2 v3 v5 - 
   8 v4 v5, -2 v0^2 - 6 v0 v1 - 2 v1^2 - 2 v0 v2 - 2 v1 v2 - 
   12 v0 v4 - 12 v1 v4 - 4 v2 v4 - 8 v0 v5 - 8 v1 v5 - 2 v2 v5 - 
   16 v4 v5, -4 v0 - 22 v4 - 22 v5, -2 v0 v1 - 4 v0 v4 - 18 v1 v4 - 
   4 v0 v5 - 18 v1 v5 - 16 v4 v5}, -48 v1 v4 v5}

where we see the fully reduced remainder at the end. Observe that PolynomialReduce needs a sorted list of variables as the third parameter. This is common to all the Gröbner basis algorithms for dealing with ideals of polynomials of several variables. Look up Gröbner basis in Wikipedia as well as the documentation provided by Mathematica. There exists an implementation in Mathematica called GroebnerBasis. I suggest that you play with these things. Observe that changing the order of variables has an effect on the output:
In[2]:=PolynomialReduce[x^7 y^5 z^3, {y - x^2, x - z}, {x, y, z}]
Out[2]={{-x^5 y^5 z^3 - x^3 y^6 z^3 - x y^7 z^3, y^8 z^3}, y^8 z^4}
In[3]:=PolynomialReduce[x^7 y^5 z^3, {y - x^2, x - z}, {y, x, z}]
Out[3]={{x^15 z^3 + x^13 y z^3 + x^11 y^2 z^3 + x^9 y^3 z^3 + x^7 y^4 z^3, 
  x^16 z^3 + x^15 z^4 + x^14 z^5 + x^13 z^6 + x^12 z^7 + x^11 z^8 + 
   x^10 z^9 + x^9 z^10 + x^8 z^11 + x^7 z^12 + x^6 z^13 + x^5 z^14 + 
   x^4 z^15 + x^3 z^16 + x^2 z^17 + x z^18 + z^19}, z^20}
In[4]:=PolynomialReduce[x^7 y^5 z^3, {y - x^2, x - z}, {y, z, x}]
Out[4]={{x^15 z^3 + x^13 y z^3 + x^11 y^2 z^3 + x^9 y^3 z^3 + 
   x^7 y^4 z^3, -x^19 - x^18 z - x^17 z^2}, x^20}

See the documentation for the meaning of the list of polynomials in the first component of the output. The last component is the remainder.
Anyway, in response to In[2] MMA first gets rid of $x$ to the extent it can. First reducing modulo $y-x^2$, i.e. replacing every occurrence of $x^2$ with a $y$: $x^7y^5z^3\mapsto xy^8z^3$. Then (using $x-z$) replaces $x$ with $z$, and ends with $y^8z^4$. It cannot do anything more, because none of the relations are about $y$ and $z$ only.
But, in response to In[3] it first seeks to eliminate $y$, and does that by substituting $y\to x^2$ leading to transformation $x^7y^5z^3\mapsto x^{17}z^3$. Then, next eliminating $z$ using $x-z$, and ends up with $x^{20}$. In response to In[4] it starts out the same way, but seeks to eliminate $x$ before $z$, and logically gives $z^{20}$ instead of $x^{20}$ as the output.
Dependence on the ordering of the variables is a well-known property of these reductions.
I need to do more studying/testing to get all the details worked out. IIRC a Gröbner basis has a form, where sequential applications of the reduction rules lead to a canonical answer (but still one that depends on the ordering of the variables).

Yes, u are right about using GroebnerBasis. A friend of mine solved my problem in Macaulay2 software, he provided that code:
R=QQ[v0,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5]
P = (v0 + v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5)*(v0^2 + v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2 + v4^2 + v5^2) - (v0 + v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5)^3
I=ideal(v0-v1+v4+v5,v2-v5,v3-v4,v0*v1,v2*v5,v3*v4)
g = gb I
P%g
And as i result i get
−48v1v4v5
Which is exactly what i need. I think your answer is pretty similar, but i'll need some tests to figure it out.

All this is basically on target. If you want a "canonical" result (for a given term ordering), use GroebnerBasis and then PolynomialReduce. In brief: `In[15]:=
polys = {v0 - v1 + v4 + v5, v2 - v5, v3 - v4, v0v1, v2v5, v3v4};
vars = {v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5};
gb = GroebnerBasis[polys, vars];
poly = (v0 + v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5)(v0^2 + v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2 +
v4^2 + v5^2) - (v0 + v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5)^3;
PolynomialReduce[poly, gb, vars][[2]]
Out[19]= -48 v1 v4 v5`

On MMA version 14.0 you can get the answer by twice applying PolynomialMod like:
ex = (v0 + v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5)*(v0^2 + v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2 + v4^2 +
       v5^2) - (v0 + v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5)^3;
polys = {v0 - v1 + v4 + v5, v2 - v5, v3 - v4, v0*v1, v2*v5, v3*v4};

tmp = PolynomialMod[ex, polys];
PolynomialMod[tmp, polys]

-48 v0 v2 v3


I view this as supporting the theory that PolynomialMod simply makes a single pass of the list of polynomials to be moded out. Doing it twice suffices in this case, but undoubtedly we can cook up occasions where $n$ passes are required.
